# how to get latest timestamp from the two columns in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

How can I get latest time from two columns eg I have two column name `start_time_a` and `start_time_b` both stores value like `2014-05-13 12:34:34` but i need to get latest time from the two columns using Python Django. I am new to django query please help me to get rid of this issue.

Example table:

```
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+ 
|  id |    start_time_a       |    start_time_b       |
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|  1  |  2014-05-13 12:34:34  |  2014-05-13 12:41:34  |
|  2  |  2014-05-13 12:40:34  |  2014-05-13 12:40:40  |
|  3  |  2014-05-13 12:20:34  |  2014-05-13 12:46:34  | 
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

and i want this output

```
|  3  |  2014-05-13 12:20:34  |  2014-05-13 12:46:34  |
```

because it has latest start_time_b from all timestamps

Comment: You want latest of the two columns into one column output?

Comment: my table has two column start_time_a and start_time_b filled with many records but i want to get single object from multiple records whose timestamp is latest

Comment: If it from multiple records, which latest time do you want to compare and fetch? latest `start_time_a` or latest `start_time_b` ?

Comment: single object having latest time either from `column1` or `column2` compare from all records

Comment: I'm assuming there's a django model behind this. If so: `Model.objects.extra({"latest": "greatest(start_time_a, start_time_b)"}).order_by('latest')[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [SQL you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23627859/3096768), you can place that into a [Django `extra()` Queryset modifier](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
qs = YourModel.objects.extra(select={
    'max_time': '''
    select * from t where (
        start_time_a in (
            select greatest(max(start_time_a), max(start_time_b)) from t
        ) or start_time_b in (
            select greatest(max(start_time_a), max(start_time_b)) from t
        )
    )'''
})

# each YourModel object in the queryset will have an extra attribute, max_time
for obj in qs:
    print obj.max_time
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting row of greatest value from two column I found this answer and it is quite usefull

```
select * from t where (
                      start_time_a in (select greatest(max(start_time_a), max(start_time_b)) from t) or
                      start_time_b in (select greatest(max(start_time_a), max(start_time_b)) from t)
                      );
```

mysql [greatest()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL solution**:

If you want to identify latest dates from all records, irrespective of other column values, you can use `MAX` function on the date columns.

**Example**:

```
select max( start_time_a ) as mx_start_time_a
       , max( start_time_b ) as mx_start_time_b
from table_name
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to get latest of two timestamp from multiple records